# Wrapping Switch Windows in Zorin

Tags: gnome3, zorin, window-switching

I am running Zorin 16 and have configured Switch Windows to use

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

and this shows me what I want. I haven't installed any special extensions.

However, the popup that appears is too wide, and I need to keep pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> (while maintaining <kbd>Alt</kbd>) to show windows that are too far to the right.

Is there a way to 'wrap' the popup window, in a similar way to how MS Windows does things?

Comment: maybe the height of the selection bar can be lowered, so that more windows will fit horizontally

Comment: That might work but I have no idea how to do it :)